# Nested lists and tuples - building inside out

Tags: python, algorithm, list, python-3.x

#### Question

Suppose that I have a list which contains two element tuples, which comprise of either further nested tuples, lists of tuples, or strings.

```
samp = [('coor', [('test', 'correlation'), 
        [('another', [('nest', 'one')]), ('tags', 'list')], ('threshold', 'foo')])]

>>> samp
[('coor',
  [('test', 'correlation'),
   [('another', [('nest', 'one')]), ('tags', 'list')],
   ('threshold', 'foo')])]
```

I also have a class, `Foo`, that can only properly accept a list which **doesn't contain any nested lists**, but **can contain other `Foo`'s**.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, li):
        self.l = li
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Foo<{0}>'.format(str(self.l))
```

I want to convert my nested structure `samp` into one giant valid `Foo`, so in this case it would look like

```
>>> big_foo
Foo<[('coor', 
      Foo<[('test', 'correlation'), 
           Foo<[('another', 
                 Foo<[('nest', 'one')]>), 
                 ('tags', 'list')]>, 
           ('threshold', 'foo')]>
      )]>
```

**How can I do this effectively?**

---

#### My thoughts

Obviously I'm going to have to build the `Foo` objects going inside-out from the deepest-nesting lists. I know I can check if an element is a tuple or a list with

```
def is_seq(el):
    return isinstance(el, collections.abc.Sequence) and not isinstance(el, str)
```

and I could check if any iterable *contains* a list at some level of nesting with something recursive like

```
def contains_list(it):
    return any(isinstance(el, list) or (isinstance(el, tuple) and contains_list(el))
                for el in it)
```

What I'm struggling with is how I will build my new structure effectively, as tuples are immutable. Recursively building the structure inside-out doesn't seem possible because tuples, and so I'm really lost for a good approach. If there's some abstraction or module which can simplify this problem for me, I would *gladly* accept it.

---

#### Motivation

I'm trying to wrap an R library with [pyRserve](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyRserve/), and need a serializable Python representation of nested named member lists in R. The only similar thing that pyRserve can serialize is a [TaggedList](http://pythonhosted.org/pyRserve/manual.html#taggedlists) which doesn't support nesting upon construction, and so now I'm left with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, li):
        self.l = li
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Foo<{0}>'.format(str(self.l))


def make_Foo(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return Foo([make_Foo(item) for item in obj])
    elif isinstance(obj, tuple):
        return tuple(make_Foo(item) for item in obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, str):
        return obj
    else:
        raise Exception("Not implemented for type {}".format(type(obj)))

samp = [('coor', [('test', 'correlation'), 
        [('another', [('nest', 'one')]), ('tags', 'list')], ('threshold', 'foo')])]

x = make_Foo(samp)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
Foo<[('coor', Foo<[('test', 'correlation'), Foo<[('another', Foo<[('nest', 'one')]>), ('tags', 'list')]>, ('threshold', 'foo')]>)]>
```

Which, if you add some whitespace...

```
Foo<[('coor', 
    Foo<[('test', 'correlation'), 
        Foo<[('another', 
            Foo<[('nest', 'one')]>), 
            ('tags', 'list')]>, 
        ('threshold', 'foo')]>
    )]>
```

Closely resembles your desired output.

Comment: Ahh, this looks great. The tuple generator I was completely overlooking. Thank you Kevin!